Disable \BreakableUnderscore in a tcblisting
Consider this MWE for a tcblisting.At first sight it seems to be working properly, as the \tl_use:N\l_tmpa_tl produces the correct output. However, this is only because TeX interprets the \l_tempa_tl as the macro \land the delimiter as tempa_tl(roughly). My request how can I disable the  the \BreakableUnderscore within the listings environment. Ideally I am looking for a solution like \BUOn \BUOff
Note: The underscore  package makes the _ active and defines a macro \_ to insert a 0pt space after it, so as to enable hyphenation. So far I was not able to redefine it and negate its effects.
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{underscore}
    \usepackage[documentation,listings]{tcolorbox}
    \begin{document}
    \ttfamily
    \meaning\_
    \begin{tcblisting}{listing options={language={[LaTeX]TeX}, keywordstyle=\color{red}}}
    \def\test{my test} 
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl{something}
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl\par
    
    \rmfamily
    \l  \par a_test_for_something\par  $a_{12}$
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \end{tcblisting}
    \end{document}

the problem can be seen more clearly, at the image, with the underscore not being colored.

